# Is there a Ruby gem that can insert JavaScript into an existing PDF file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

Are there any Ruby gems that can open an existing PDF and insert JavaScript into it?

I  found [prawn-js](https://github.com/yob/prawn-js) which can insert the JavaScript, but it will not work for me because Prawn cannot open existing PDF files, it can only generate new ones.

Comment: Why not generating a new PDF with prawn-js and add the content of the base PDF (that you could retrieve with another PDF reader)?

Comment: That's actually what I wanted to do. However, the pdf files that I am working with must be generated from a Word doc with [doPDF](http://www.dopdf.com/) so unfortunately I cannot generate the pdf with prawn and insert javascript with prawn-js. I thought I could just use prawn to open my existing pdf file and use prawn-js to insert the javascript too but it does not seem like prawn can open existing pdf's for editing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a popular gem called [WickedPDF](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) which internally uses shell utility [WkHtmlToPDF](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf).

If you refer to the wiki, while rendering PDF, if you specify

```
   :disable_javascript=> false
```

that should help you out. Let us know, if it helped you or you need something else. Btw, are you using some charts/graphs in your PDF?

Comment: That's not what that option is for. That disables running of javascript in the headless browser before trying to print the html page to a PDF.